# How can i select file on phone not sdcard?

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream, android-file

I mean I want to define a file path on phone memory not sdcard.

I want to  use this :

```
FileOutputStream out3 = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/a/b.txt");
```

this gives error.
How can i fix this?
thanks.

error

```
 09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kelime.tekerrur/com.example.kelime.tekerrur.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 19:49:11.050: E/AndroidRuntime(20214):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
File imgFile = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory()+“/test_image.jpg”);
```

Comment: so, if I write like this : new File(Environment.getRootDirectory()+“/aaa/test_image.jpg”);  it creates aaa directory if it does not exist or I manually create aaa directory?

Comment: FileOutputStream out3 = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/a/b.txt"); this gives error. error is null

Comment: maybe the directory 'a' is not yet created. Try this - 
File dir = new File(root.getRootDirectory() + "/a");
if(!dir.exists()) { dir.mkdirs(); }

Comment: I already did but it doesnt work. root.getRootDirectory() return system/a/

Comment: it says out3 is null. why out3 is null

Comment: File myFile = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory()+“/a/b.txt”);
File dir = new File(root.getRootDirectory() + "/a"); if(!dir.exists()) { dir.mkdirs(); } 
FileOutputStream out3 = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

Comment: that is what i was thinking. Why not write to sdcard

Comment: because some phones doesn have sdcard

Comment: are you trying it on emulator or a real phone?

Comment: I think i have reached my android limits here :(. Do let me know if you get a solution.

Answer (score 2):

To get the SD-Card path you have to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` 
The `Environment.getRootDirectory()` which Mukesh suggested returns the device root "/" - you can't write (or read) in this Directory on a non-rooted-device.